# single quotes vs double quotes, how to arrange?

Tags: php, html

Please let me know how to writte the below code so as to work because as it is it doesn't work

```
echo "<a href='$row['url']'>$row['link_text']</a>";
```

Comment: It doesn't work because he has a `'` inside another `'`.

Comment: What happened to the "lacks basic understanding" close reason?

Comment: hmm... This man just new in php. Why many down votes in question. This is not human!

Comment: I've been asking myself the same question, when they changed the options some days ago @JonathonReinhart The new options don't make sense.

Comment: Well, he got a IDE with syntax highlighting ... this isnt too difficult to solve. Btw, this isnt even php, this is more html.

Comment: @YUNOWORK Try putting `echo "<a href='$row['url']'>$row['link_text']</a>";` in a .html file. This is certainly PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `'` twice, so you need to escape them or just remove them in this case:

```
echo "<a href='$row[url]'>$row[link_text]</a>";
```

Comment: Does that actually work?! I've never seen a statement written that way before.

Answer (score 3):

Write so you can read it next time. Also syntax highlight is better this way:

```
echo '<a href="' . $row['url'] . '">' . $row['link_text'] . '</a>';
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have to insert complex variables like array values inside strings, usually [`printf`](http://php.net/printf) or [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) is more clear and less error-prone.:

```
printf("<a href='%s'>%s</a>", $row['url'], $row['link_text']);
```

Comment: Well, then in this case you probably mean to use `printf` in your example too :)

Comment: @DainisAbols d'oh! thank you for noticing

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
echo "<a href='".$row['url']."'>".$row['link_text']."</a>";
```

Also this:

```
echo "<a href='{$row['url']}'>{$row['link_text']}</a>";
```

It's personal preference.

It's because you've put a `'` inside another `'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<a href='{$row['url']}'>{$row['link_text']}</a>";
```

or

```
echo "<a href='" . $row['url'] . "'>" . $row['link_text'] . "</a>";
```

Choose the one more to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with.

```
echo "<a href='".$row['url']."'>".$row['link_text']."</a>";
```

Or

```
echo "<a href='{$row['url']}'>{$row['link_text']}</a>";
```

Or

```
echo '<a href="'.$row["url"].'">'.$row["link_text"].'</a>';
```